# Update nth element in delimited line [unix scripting]

Tags: csv, unix, sed, scripting, delimited

i have a .temp file that contains comma-delimited lines:

```
abc,1,000,aaa,zzz,2,234,OOO,00001,01,123,214
def,2,003,bbb,yyy,4,345,PPP,00002,02,133,224
ghi,3,011,ccc,xxx,6,456,QQQ,00003,03,143,234
jkl,4,012,ddd,www,8,567,RRR,00004,04,153,244
...
```

each line is read and 3rd column is used to update 9th column

i'm able to do this using:

```
indexToUpdate=9

updatedLine="$(echo "$line" | sed "s/[^,]*/$new9thColumnData/$indexToUpdate")"
```

my question is, is there a faster way to update 9th column data aside from using sed?

Comment: There are many ways this can be achieved (cut and paste come to mind) however this GNU sed solution for replacing the 9th column with the 3rd might help - `sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){3}([^,]*,){5})[^,]*,/\1\2/' file`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to potong's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822164/update-nth-element-in-delimited-line-unix-scripting#comment123423007_69822164), you could use e.g. awk:

```
awk -F ',' '{ OFS=FS; $9=$3; print }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl -lanF, -e 'print join ",", @F[0..7,2,9..$#F]' file`

or, like awk above:

`perl -lanF, -e '$F[8]=$F[2]; print join ",", @F' file`

Uses perl's autosplit to split on commas, which creates the @F array, which is then printed in a different order.

Not that perl is faster than either sed or awk...